# How do I run a script that uses django in the background

Tags: python, json, django

This is my code, I want to write data to my django database with a python script, because the data is generated and saved in a json file about once a day. The new data needs to be written to my django databse when the new json file is created

```
def write_stuff(self):
    """Write stuff to database"""
    var = Match(match_id=self.match_id, match_date=self.match_date, team_a=self.team_a, team_b=self.team_b,
                    winner=self.winner, event=self.event, closed=self.closed)
    var.save()
```

When I run this code I keep on getting an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I have tried everything on SO to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and even tried every possible path in the manage.py and wsgi.py files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could use a django management command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is not bootstrapping Django

I would look into making a [custom Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/).

which you can then run with

```
./manage.py importcsv
```

This will run a command within the Django environment with all settings initialised correctly

Comment: Thank you, will check it out and let you know!